# iOS limit background time

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I need to run some code when the user enters a background state. The default time I was getting for when I entered the background on iOS 9 was 10 seconds. I needed a bit more than that, so I found that this code will extend the time to 3 minutes:

```
- (void)extendBackgroundRunningTime {
    if (_backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
        // if we are in here, that means the background task is already running.
        // don't restart it.
        return;
    }
    NSLog(@"Attempting to extend background running time");

    __block Boolean self_terminate = YES;

    _backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"DummyTask" expirationHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"Background task expired by iOS");
        if (self_terminate) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:_backgroundTask];
            _backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
        }
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"Background task started");

        while (true) {
            NSLog(@"background time remaining: %8.2f", [UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining);
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
        }

    });
}
```

However, my task doesn't need all of this extra time, and I would like to conserve as much battery as possible. Is there any way to use this or similar code to get 1 minute of background time, or some other value between 10 and 180 seconds?

Comment: You can't control the remaining background remaining time. You can only start/end the background task. Sometimes the 180 seconds can extend, I couldn't replicate it but that happens randomly.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `endBackgroundTask:` once you are done with your background processing. If you are done before the 3 minute time allotted to you, that should end your background processing early and let iOS suspend you. I haven't tested it to verify, but that's what the docs suggest.

Comment: Well I still have other processes running during this time as well. The app is still awake even if I manually kill this task. I need to sleep the entire app after 1 minute